How to report abuse of legal aid services?
Often legal aid services have a clear caveat requiring that you are eligible if your household income is under X% of the federal poverty level. X can be 125 to 200. If someone is abusing this by using legal aid services while being at a household income above these levels, where and how might one raise or report this concern?

It might be that coverage would still be provided/extended if the request was for a dependent within the household against one or more of the responsible (aged) householders or other dependents of the household.

The mechanism depends on the legal aid provider. I expect all legal aid providers would want to know if they have been misled into providing someone with legal aid.
One example: Legal Aid Ontario, "Report suspected fraud or wrongdoing."

england-and-wales
In England you can report Legal Aid fraud via a special whistle-blower number and website.

The Counter Fraud & Investigations (CFI) team is responsible for investigating allegations of fraud by solicitors, barristers and third-party experts carrying out legal aid work. They also investigate allegations of fraud by clients in receipt of both civil and criminal legal aid.
To report suspected fraudulent activity you should e-mail CFI: laacounterfraud@justice.gov.uk or contact your Contract Manager.
Alternatively you can report your concerns anonymously by completing the ‘Reporting Fraud’ form.

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/legal-aid-agency-special-investigations
